# Sniffing https/SSL traffic with Burp Suite Proxy in combination with Wireshark

Tags: ssl, openssl, wireshark, packet-sniffers

What I'm trying: to sniff all packets, including encrypted, from an iDevice.

What I use: Burp Suite Proxy which generates a CA-signed per-host certificate and Wireshark for all other traffic.

What isn't working: The Burp Suite Proxy does not capture all traffic, Wireshark does. But I can't get Wireshark to decrypt https-sessions.

What I've tried: I tried to create a self-signed certificate and use it with Burp Suite Proxy and Wireshark. I managed to decrypt some traffic both with Burp Suite Proxy as well as Wireshark. The problem is that in case I use a self-signed certificate some handshakes fail, this does not happen if I use the CA-signed per-host certificates that Burp Suite Proxy automatically creates. The problem is that I can't extract private keys from those certificates for Wireshark.

Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Comment: is it certain handshakes that always fail or at random?

Comment: Can't really say, but my hunch is that it fails at certain handshakes.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes device apps check for the signature of the certificate, so maybe that's the reason it's not working.